# Jquery selected values

Tags: jquery

```
   $(document).ready(function () {  
                  //Store the sub types      
                     StoreSubTypes();
                     //Set up company Type on Change  
                     $("#option").change(CompanyTypeOnChange);
                     $(".status").change(InsuranceTypeChange);
                     CompanyTypeOnChange(); 

                         } );
```

Comment: What kind of error you got? What place of code not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are missing a value.

For example change `<option>Car Loan</option>` to `<option value="Car Loan">Car Loan</option>`

Comment: It is that a test to make the jquery work but the values are read from sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

value is an attribute of the option tag(`<option value="">`), and this,rather than the textnode value which in the option tag, will be received when form post.

if you just want to get the textnode value,then use some option.innerHTML,or $(option).text().